# Nuget Pack not including new files

Tags: c#, nuget

I've added new models and helpers to my project, but when I run `nuget pack` and install the package in my project I don't see the new items in the Assembly Explorer nor can I use them.  Am I missing something during the build that wouldn't include new files added to the package?

I'm using visual studio 2017 and the nuget cli

Comment: If you go to Project -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Installed, do you see your NuGet package listed there under "Installed?"  Did you add `using` directives to your project's code to utilize the package?

Comment: I do see it as installed. If i look in assembly explorer I'm missing items. Such as I made a model called TestModel.  When I look under models its not there in my package.  I've nuget pack over and over

Comment: Please [edit] your question, include the specific NuGet Package name, and details, and please show a [mcve] of your sample including `using` this package.  We definitely need a bit more detail to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you didn't change the package version when you changed the code and packed again. NuGet is designed such that the package id/version produces an immutable package. This means it's valid to download a package, say Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1 from nuget.org just once, and every time you use that package in any project on the same computer you can re-use the same download, rather than having to download it every time you restore/build the project.

This causes some people problems when they're trying to test their packages. One option is to take advantage of Semantic Versioning and use `1.0.1-preview.1`, `1.0.1-preview.2`, so every single build of the project has a unique version number. In addition, or instead, you could use a `nuget.config` to set the `globalPackagesFolder` to a different location that gets cleared every time you change the package. If you delete the "cache", it can't reuse the old contents. But this only works if you control the machines that use the package. Once you publish the package where anyone else can use the package, you will cause problems if you change the contents, which is why nuget.org doesn't allow deleting packages, only unlisting them.

However, another possible solution is to just not use packages and simply use project references. Some people have the misconception that if you have two packages, one depends on the other, that they need to use package references to make sure NuGet dependency information flows. That's not correct. If you pack with the MSBuild pack targets (highly recommended, and the default option for SDK style projects), NuGet will always convert project references into NuGet dependencies. `nuget pack` will convert project references into dependencies when the other project also has its own `nuspec` file. When you test your project with project references, you never have to worry about immutable packages. Just pack when it's ready, but it's not needed for testing.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have a .nuspec file (at the same level than your .csproj) that you need to edit to include new files?